# How to pass double quoted string to sc.exe for binPath

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am trying to come up with a PowerShell process to quote service paths that contain spaces. This is because of [Qualys 105484](https://success.qualys.com/support/s/article/000003570).

I know that the parsing engine is complicated and running cmd commands with embedded quotes can be difficult to say the least. I'm hoping I am close and another set of eyes will help.

the cmd command I am trying to run from PowerShell is

```
sc create OcaLogSvc binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc\""
```

Here are some attempts and a comment below each showing the result that appears for the binPath

```
$serviceName = "OcaLogSvc"
& sc.exe config $serviceName binPath= '""\""C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc\""""'
# ""C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc""

& sc.exe config $serviceName binPath= '""\""C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc""\""'
# ""C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc""

& sc.exe config $serviceName binPath= '"""\"C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc\""""'
# ""C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc""

& sc.exe config $serviceName binPath= "\C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc\"
# \C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc"
```

Which I verify by running

```
sc.exe qc $serviceName | sls "BINARY"
```

Tried several other combinations but those above were the only ones that succeeded.

Likely I am going to give up and instead pipe some string into .bat files that I can call instead. That or edit the registry directly. I just feel that this is something possible.

I cannot use the stop parsing parameter as I intend to use variables for the path names as I discover them. I also am only mass targeting commands that do not have arguments. I will address those manually or at least in another fashion than what I am trying to do here.

I also tried to examine cmd strings with `CommandLineToArgvW` via `Split-CommandLine` but that knowledge hasn't translated well to the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your looking for:

`'"C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc"'` - which will result in a string `"C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc"`

Issue your trying to remediate only exists due to spaces in the command. Another option might be to use the old DOS name `c:\progra~1\` or install you app to a folder that doesnt contain a space like `C:\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc`

Comment: That unfortunately does not work as those inner quotes are consumed along the way.

`BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc`

Comment: ```c:\progra~1\``` is clever. I could convert the existing path in the way that https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/converting-file-paths-to-8-3-part-1 outlines. e.g. `(New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFile($path).ShortPath`

Comment: Im not sure if its Powershell or sc.exe thats messing with you here - does SC work from CMD? If so `cmd /c sc config ...` from powershell might work too. Using the shortpath is kinda side-stepping the issue but should work fine. You could just patch the services ImagePath registry key with `Set-ItemProperty` after using sc? Maybe also try `Start-Process` instead of `&`?

Comment: Theres also the pure powershell  `Get-Service`, `Remove-Service` and `New-Service` which you could pull current values, patch them, then remove the service and recreate it with the modified params?

Comment: I would still run into issues with either of those as PowerShell is still parsing those commands. Yes, works fine from sc in cmd.

Comment: Native PowerShell cmdlets, at least in 5.x, don't allow manipulation of the binary path

Comment: You are correct, you cant update it, but if you remove and re-create the service you have to provide the binPath see param: `[-BinaryPathName] <String>` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2 -

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing out to the this [document](https://success.qualys.com/support/s/article/000003570)

I tried to modify a service in my machine using `sc.exe` command but failed to update it, although the command ran successfully!
Then I thought that we could update the exe paths using registry keys

as you may now, the services details exist on registry under:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$service
```

so in order to update your service with quotes you just need to update it in registry using the command `Set-Itemproperty` as follow:

```
$service = "OcaLogSvc"
Set-Itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$service" -Name 'ImagePath' -value '"C:\Program Files\AppRecovery\Agent\R3LogService\OcaLogSvc"'
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing in the mean time.

Comment: try this, it works on my machine :)

Comment: I know.... I am already doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a working PowerShell solution for this!

```
sc.exe config myService binPath= "`"`"`"C:\Directory with spaces\something.exe`"`"`" --some-parameter"
```

It's stupid, but the triple-escaped quote within a quoted string seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\system32>sc config Pr_Ince1 binPath=**""D:\IY In OUSS\test.exe"** -XNInsce1 -K

[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

eg : "slash"D:\ path here"